# second ExecuteReader() doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I have a code which checks the validity of user and then, if a user is valid it inserts certain values in the database.

My problem is when After I query my database to check if a user is valid and after that i try to pass the additional value to its account the flow stops when I invoke ExecuteReader() for the second time.

There is no error, or anything like that. I tried to substitute ExecuteReader() with ExecuteNoneQuery but still it's not working. I tried all the query in mysql command prompt they are working perfectly. I really can't understand what am I doing wrong there. Can anyone help me please?

Here is the code:

```
 Try
            myconn.Open()
            Dim stquery As String = "SELECT * from accountstbl WHERE SE_ID = " & Id.Text
            Dim smd = New MySqlCommand(stquery, myconn)
            Dim myreader = smd.ExecuteReader()
            If Not myreader.HasRows Then
                errorUser.Visible = True

            Else
                myreader.Read()
                Dim name As String = myreader.Item("user_name").ToString()

                Dim stquery2 = "INSERT into backup VALUES (" & name & ", '" & Info & "')"
                Dim smd2 = New MySqlCommand(stquery2, myconn)
                Dim Myreader2 As MySqlDataReader
                'smd.ExecuteNonQuery()'
                'THE CODE STOPS HERE'
                Myreader2 = smd2.ExecuteReader()
                'Myreader2.Read()'

                MsgBox("The BACKUP INFORMATION HAS BEEN SAVED")


            End If
            myconn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "');"
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)
            myconn.Close()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your second query is an update, not a select, you need to execute it using the `ExecuteNonQuery` method. Your commented-out code shows an attempt to call `ExecuteNonQuery` but on the wrong command object (`smd` when it should be `smd2`). Try something like this instead:

```
myreader.Read()
Dim name As String = myreader.Item("user_name").ToString()

Dim stquery2 = "INSERT into backup VALUES (" & name & ", '" & Info & "')"
Dim smd2 = New MySqlCommand(stquery2, myconn)
smd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns the number of rows updated as an `int` value, so you can capture it if it's valuable to you. In your case it's probably not, but here's how you'd check anyway:

```
int rowsAdded = smd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (rowsAdded == 1) {
   // expected this
} else {
   // didn't expect this
}
```

Finally, concatenating strings to build SQL commands can leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Please take a look at using parameterized queries. There's a decent example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute nested `Reader`, you have to create another `connection`. You need somethig like

```
smd2 = New MySqlCommand(stquery2, myconn2)' myconn2 is another connection
```

OR

Set "`MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in your connection string.

Also, use `ExecuteNonQuery()` for Inserting

```
Dim name As String = myreader("user_name").ToString()
Dim stquery2 = "INSERT into backup VALUES ('" & name & "', '" & Info & "')"
Dim smd2 = New MySqlCommand(stquery2, myconn)
smd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Please use [Parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx)

Comment: That is what perplexes me grately. I simply can't understand what is the matter with the code

Comment: when i press the button nothing changes at all

Comment: I tried to create second connection(because if I add MultipleActiveResultSets=True it says keyword is not supported) and also closed previous datareader. But the problem is still there

Comment: Create another connection, your second query is an insert no need for `ExecuteReader()`

Comment: I've tried to add MsgBoxe after every single line of code one by one to trace where the execution stops and the last palce the message showed up was when I inserted it after `Dim Myreader2 As MySqlDataReader`

Answer (score 0):

The logic is that you need to close your first reader (myreader) before executing another reader (MyReader2) on the same connection.

Comment: ok. But in that case I would've prompted with a mistake. But it doesn't occure.

Comment: wait I will try to close the existing one.

Comment: @nelsonb you are correct but give the answer with code would be appreciated